# Magento 2: How to export tables by name using REST API

Tags: magento2, database, rest-api

How can i export tables using the REST API. I've looked through the devdocs and dont see any endpoints to do this? The tables i want are standard ones like `customer_entity` and `sales_order`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting tables using the REST API is not a common use case, as the API is typically used for creating, updating, and retrieving specific data entities rather than exporting entire tables.

However, if you need to export tables such as customer_entity and sales_order using the REST API, one approach could be to create custom API endpoints that allow you to retrieve the data you need in the format you want.

Here are some general steps you could follow to create a custom API endpoint for exporting data from a table:

1. Define the endpoint: Determine the URL and HTTP method for your custom endpoint. For example, you could use /api/export/customers to export customer data, and use the HTTP GET method to retrieve the data.
2. Implement the endpoint logic: In your custom endpoint's controller or route handler, write code to retrieve the data you need from the Magento database. You can use Magento's built-in data models and database access methods to retrieve data from tables such as customer_entity and sales_order.
3. Format the data: Once you have retrieved the data, you will need to format it in a way that can be easily exported. This might involve converting it to CSV, Excel, JSON, or another format depending on your requirements.
4. Return the formatted data: Finally, you will need to return the formatted data in the response to the API request. Make sure to set the appropriate content type headers and status codes so that the client can process the response correctly.

Keep in mind that this approach will require you to write custom code and may involve some performance and security considerations. It's also worth noting that exporting large tables or datasets via the REST API could be resource-intensive and slow, so you may need to consider alternative methods such as using command-line tools or SQL queries to export the data.